# Avoiding unncessary use of lambda for calls to object methods

Tags: python

Consider the following code, which simply calls a method on each member of a list:

```
class Demo:
    def make_change(self):
        pass

foo = [Demo(), Demo(), Demo()]
map(lambda x: x.make_change(), foo)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without the long-winded `lambda` syntax? For example, in Scala, something similar to `map(_.make_change(), foo)` works. Does Python have an equivalent?

Comment: gnibbler raised the point that it's not pythonic to use map just for side-effects. Let's assume that make_change doesn't have side-effects, and instead returns something that I want to collect as a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not very pythonic to use map just for side-effects

so why not

```
for item in foo:
    item.make_change()
```

This will run faster than using map

you *can* put it on one line if you insist, but I wouldn't

```
for item in foo:item.make_change()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
operator.methodcaller('make_change')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm with gnibbler on the pythonicity. Apart from that, this is also possible:

```
map(Demo.make_change, foo)
```

It has problems, though:

```
class Demo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 2
    def make_change(self):
        self.x = 5

class SubDemo(Demo):
    def make_change(self):
        self.y = 7

d = Demo()
s = SubDemo()
map(Demo.make_change, [d, s])

assert d.x == 5 and s.y == 7 # oops!
```